# How can I modify the selectbox column length in streamlit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, streamlit

I have the below code:

```
import streamlit as st
import subprocess

git_output = subprocess.run(['git', 'branch', '-a'], cwd='/home/demo', capture_output=True, text=True).stdout

br_list = git_output.split('\n')

select = st.sidebar.selectbox('Option', list(filter(lambda k: 'remotes/origin' in k and '1v' in k, br_list)))
```

The problem is that streamlit checkbox limit the characters up to 34, and my results in the list is around 60 for each. how can I modify it so the selectbox will be longer and present the entire string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the below solution:

https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/2058#issuecomment-816989601